# js array sort nor working for custom logic

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an Issue in array sort. I have custom logic in displaying the array. The object has a code column and has a code `('A' or 'B' or 'C')`. I have to sort in records to display first `'B'`, `'A'` and `last 'C'`.

My code is in [`slackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-jpfqt3?file=index.ts).

Here is code

```
list.sort(function (el1, el2) {
  if (el1.codeNumber > el2.codeNumber) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (el1.codeNumber < el2.codeNumber) {
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify the code by using an object for getting the wanted order of an item with a certain `code`.

```js
const
    list = [{ name: 'Bala', age: 21, code: 'A' }, { name: 'Bala', age: 22, code: 'A' }, { name: 'Bala', age: 23, code: 'C' }, { name: 'Bala', age: 24, code: 'A' }, { name: 'Bala', age: 25, code: 'B' }, { name: 'Bala', age: 26, code: 'B' }, { name: 'Bala', age: 27, code: 'B' }, { name: 'Bala', age: 28, code: 'A' }, { name: 'Bala', age: 29, code: 'B' }, { name: 'Bala', age: 30, code: 'C' }, { name: 'Bala', age: 31, code: 'C' }, { name: 'Bala', age: 31, code: 'C' }, { name: 'Bala', age: 28, code: 'A' }],
    order = { B: 1, A: 2, C: 3 };
    
list.sort((a, b) => order[a.code] - order[b.code]);

console.log(list);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This code works. However it's for Angular typescript project. The above code produces different result in typescript. can you try it in my link 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-yq7rme?file=index.ts

Comment: i have no idea of typescript. sorry.